# Is the integer-factorization problem (used for many cryptographic applications) NP-Complete?

Tags: cryptography, computer-science

As the question states, does the integer-factorization problem fall into the class of NP-Complete problems?

Comment: Integer-factorization is considered NP, but not NP-complete since no reduction proof is known.

Comment: It is definitely NP, but we don't know whether or not it's P.  It's believed not to be P.

NP does *not* mean "not P".  All of P is NP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Factoring:

- It is not known to be NP-complete. (No reduction from an NP-complete problem has been found.)
- It is not known *not* to be NP-complete either (if we knew the latter about some nontrivial problem in NP, it would mean P≠NP, so the latter is not surprising).
- No polynomial factoring algorithm is known (or believed to exist), so it is believed not to be in P either.

The informal consensus/belief is that this is one of the "in-between" problems that are not in P and are not NP-complete. Of course, this belief is less strong and widely held than P≠NP.

Answer (score -1):

Yes ,because you can make reduction to the factorization problem for any integer number to decision problem by using a function  when the answer is (No) that means this number is a composite  then you can track their prime factors .

Comment: I think you could become quite famous if you could prove the problem is NP complete. It's not been proven to be NP complete or not NP complete.